# ASP.NET MVC OpenId Mixed with Ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, openid-connect

I have an MVC app that I'm migrating from a "proprietary" auth mechanism to OpenID Connect

This is the configuration

```cs
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
    CookieName = "AuthCookieName"
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "OpenId",
    ClientId = "myClient",
    Authority = "https://mykeycloakinstance...",
    Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
    ResponseType = "code id_token token",
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
    },
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
        {
            n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = n.Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
        }
    },
    SaveTokens = true,
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies"
});
```

The app mainly uses the MVC paradigm (i.e. the server pulls info from the database and injects them into a `cshtml` view file)

But some pages/views also use AJAX (i.e. call endpoints that return JSON data and render the JSON in the client side) and this is where my problem is.

Every 1 minute my access token refreshes (I'm aware that I can change that number but I prefer to leave it relatively low).
The "MVC" part of the application handles it perfectly by quickly redirecting the user to the IDP and back

But pages that perform Ajax request works for the first minute (as long as the access token is valid), and then break and start returning 302 (the AJAX request tries to redirect to the IDP)

[image]

Once I refresh the page, the session refreshes and AJAX request start working again (at least for the next minute), but some pages are meant to be "long living" so expecting the user to refresh the page every once in a while is not acceptable.

How can I make AJAX requests work correctly? Should I consider using the implicit flow in my client? If so, what would I do with the "MVC" part?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to handle all the tokens in the backend, so the client (browser) does not need to deal with token refresh.

The Implicit flow is deprecated in OAuth 2.1 should no longer be used for new projects.

Two links worth reading are:

- https://leastprivilege.com/2020/03/31/spas-are-dead/
- https://leastprivilege.com/2019/01/18/an-alternative-way-to-secure-spas-with-asp-net-core-openid-connect-oauth-2-0-and-proxykit/

If you are using ASP.NET Core, then you can use the IdentityModel library and its built access token management. It can automatically refresh the access tokens using your refresh tokens.
https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetcore/web.html

Comment: That's what I'm already doing. I'm now using the implicit flow right now. All tokens are handled on the server and client communicates with server using a session cookie. The problem is, as I said in the post is that the cookie refreshes only if the user refreshes the page, so pages that use AJAX heavily and don't rely on the user refreshing, break once the cookie/access token expires.
I was able to mitigate it by having an hidden iFrame that periodically redirects the user to the IDP which in turns refreshes the cookie but I'm not sure if it's really the best practice...

Comment: updated my answer. for new development, you should consider using the authorization code flow with PKCE, as that is more secure than the implicit flow. You could also change so that the session token lasts longer?

Comment: I'm using .NET Framework (legacy application). Also, I can increase the lifespan of the access token but that would just delay the problem

Comment: in my experience having a hidden iframe is a perfect viable solution to refresh the cookie and or tokens.